# Cannot install BytecoinWallet.deb

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, deb

I downloaded the latest BytecoinWallet but for some reason it doesn't want to install.

At first I gave it perms with:

```
chmod 755 BytecoinWallet-1.0.11.amd64.deb
```

After that I tried to install it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i BytecoinWallet-1.0.11.amd64.deb
```

And the output:

```
(Reading database ... 268595 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack BytecoinWallet-1.0.11.amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bytecoinwallet (1.0.11) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from 'BytecoinWallet-1.0.11.amd64.deb' to decompressor pipe: unexpected end of file or stream
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive BytecoinWallet-1.0.11.amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/bin/bytecoinwallet' to '/usr/bin/bytecoinwallet.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160523-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 BytecoinWallet-1.0.11.amd64.deb
```

After that i tried to fix it with:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

It didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might note that that particular version is smaller than all other releases by several megabytes so I suspect a faulty archive at the developer's end.

- `BytecoinWallet-1.0.11.amd64.deb` is 539.9kb
- `BytecoinWallet-1.0.10.amd64.deb` is 3.2MB

Here is a screenshot of the SourceForge download page to show this:

[image]

Good news is that the slightly older version seems to install fine:

```
wget --content-disposition \
https://sourceforge.net/projects/bytecoin-bcn/files/BytecoinWallet/BytecoinWallet-1.0.10.amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i BytecoinWallet-1.0.10.amd64.deb
```

But I have not tested the application itself, only the install process:

```
andrew@athens:~$ bytecoinwallet --version
bytecoinwallet 1.0.10
```